# Error: java: invalid flag: -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration

1. Updated to IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2
2. I have Java JDK9 as default Java Module. I am familiar with targeting different JVMS for compilation.
3. I get Error when module attempts to build after the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PermGen space has been [replaced by the Metaspace in Java 8](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6964458). That option was deprecated in Java 8 and has been completely removed in Java 9, see e.g. [JDK-8038827](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8038827?focusedCommentId=13480515&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-13480515):

> All VM options related to PermGen were deprecated in JDK 8 and removed in JDK 9, on all platforms. They will not be brought back.

You should have seen something along "Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0" previously.

Comment: I do remember seeing ignoring option* and not resolving warnings.
Note to self, fix warnings before they become problems.

Answer (score 5):

I had to remove Override compiler parameter per module, They made it in there from previous configurations

***Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler***

[image]

Comment: ahh.. it was starting to get frustrating until I stumbled on this answer and it worked.